# Assigning an autoreleased object to a retained property

Tags: objective-c, release, exc-bad-access, autorelease

I have a property with name bgImage in my custom UITableViewCell class (MyTableCell). Its declared like

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *bgImage;
```

in dealloc method of MyTableCell, i release btImage

```
[bgImage release];
self.bgImage = nil;
[super dealloc];
```

Now what I do with this bgImage in cellForRowAtIndexPath is that i assign it a autoreleased object

```
myTableCell.bgImage.image = [Util imageNamedNoCache:@"image.png"];
```

**where imageNamedNoCache returns an autoreleased image.**

My problem is that I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS in dealloc method of MyTableCell.
Can anyone please tell me why I am getting this?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You release `bgImage` twice in dealloc, that's why you get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.
You release it yourself and it is released in generated setter method when you do `self.bgImage = nil;`